# Contact Form 7 backend email to different Adress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, contact-form-7

I am looking to add a second Email to contact form without using wordpress dashboard.

I would like to add it into the contact form 7 SOURCE files on my server.

Do you have any IDEA where should I add the Email in the source file?

So that if someone fills the fotm out it the email will go to the Email entered in Wordpress Plugin Settings and also to the Email I have netered in the backend.

Could it be somewhere in this path?

wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\admin\admin-functions.php:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['wpcf7-mail-recipient'] ) ) {
```

$mail['recipient'] = trim( $_POST['wpcf7-mail-recipient'] );

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure bt I am supposing it as email address is statically predefined obviously.
So let' say you have email address 
"admin@gmail.com"

So here

```
wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\admin\admin-functions.php:
```

mention one variable as

```
$email = "admin@gmail.com";
if ( isset( $_POST['wpcf7-mail-recipient'] )  && !empty($email)) 
{
  //Rest of the remaining code of plugin.
}
Also at the time of email
$mail['recipient'] = trim( $_POST['wpcf7-mail-recipient'] );
$mail['recipient'] = trim( $email );
```

Note make `$email` as a global variable so it can be used anywhere.